# Set default File to upload using Apache commons file upload

Tags: java, file-upload, default, apache-commons-fileupload

I am using `apache commons file upload 1.1` . Currently i am using `parseRequest(request)` to parse the items from the request .

Now i have an additional request to upload a file . something like `default` file if user doesn't upload any.

Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`parseRequest`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html#parseRequest%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) returns a list of `FileItem`s. So, when the list is empty there was no file uploaded.

Therefore, you just need to test if the list is empty. Taking an example from [Using FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html)

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
if (items.isEmpty()) {
    // process some default file
} else {
    // process uploaded file
}
```

*Update:*

According to [Processing the uploaded items](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html#Processing_the_uploaded_items), you can have files and regular form fields mixed in the request. You can iterate through the parameters, set a flag when you see a file upload, and act accordingly afterwards

```
// Process the uploaded items
boolean fileUploaded = false;
Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
        processFormField(item);
    } else {
        processUploadedFile(item);
        fileUploaded = true;
    }
}

if (!fileUploaded) {
    // process some default file
}
```

Comment: But i need to retrieve the other attributes from the form except `file`  as it will be `Null` . i need to `getParameter` such as type, month etc. is that possible ?